# Flutter unit testing streams that do map

Tags: flutter, testing, flutter-test

I did stuck with testing streams that do some transformations before returning the value. I am using Firestore as my data storage and have a separated data layer that performs some mapping from `DocumentSnapshot<T>` to my model. Here is an example of the repo:

```dart
class RequestsRepository {
  final CollectionReference<Request> _requestsCollection =
      getIt<FirebaseFirestore>().collection('requests').withConverter<Request>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Request.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
          toFirestore: (request, _) => request.toJson());

  Stream<Request?> observe(String id) {
    return _requestsCollection
        .doc(id)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.exists ? snapshot.data() : null);
    });
  }
}
```

And now I'd like to cover `observe(id)` function with tests. Here is the solution I came to and below I'll explain why:

```dart
test('request exists', () async {
      // WHEN
      final stream = repository.observe(request.id);

      // expected events
      final events = [null, request, request..completed = true, null];
      var eventIndex = 0;

      // THEN
      stream.listen(expectAsync1((value) async {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
        expect(value, events[eventIndex]);
        eventIndex++;
      }, max: -1));

      // GIVEN
      await firestore
          .collection('requests')
          .doc(request.id)
          .set(request.toJson());

      request.completed = true;

      await firestore
          .collection('requests')
          .doc(request.id)
          .set(request.toJson());

      // reset request data
      request.completed = false;
    });
```

I tried `emitsInOrder` stream matcher however it fails, because I'm doing mapping inside the `observe(id)` function and that result in actually not `request` object but `_MapStream<DocumentSnapshot<Request?>, Request?>` instead because of the logic that stream map function follows:

```dart
Stream<S> map<S>(S convert(T event)) {
    return new _MapStream<T, S>(this, convert);
  }
```

The solution I came to did work for this case but it did not for other tests and also the solution is smelly. Any suggestions how to tests these kind of streams?

UPDATE:

Per comment from @pskink here is the demo test that fails with the same reason:

```dart
class Test {
  Stream<B> observe() {
    return Stream.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 500), (i) => A(i * 10))
        .map((i) => B('s${i.a}'));
  }
}

class A {
  final int a;
  A(this.a);

  bool operator ==(o) => o is A && a == o.a;
  int get hashCode => a.hashCode;
}

class B {
  final String b;
  B(this.b);

  bool operator ==(o) => o is B && b == o.b;
  int get hashCode => b.hashCode;
}

void main() {
  test('mapped stream: A > B', () async {
    final stream = Test().observe();
    expect(stream, emitsInOrder([B('s0'), B('s10'), B('s20'), B('s30')]));
  });
}
```

It passes with the test so far.

Comment: post a short code snippet that can be reproduced easily (without any firestore deps), something like: `test('mapped stream: int > String', () async {
final stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 500), (i) => i * 10)
.take(4)
.map((i) => 's$i');
expect(stream, emitsInOrder(['s0', 's10', 's20', 's30']));
});` - here `Stream<int>` is `Stream.map()`ed to `Stream<String>` and the test is passed

Comment: @pskink yeah, sorry, my mistake. So I've updated the test to be close to what I see and looks like the short code snippet works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pskink so far to identifying that the issue is not with stream conversion (even though logs look pretty unreadable). I had to make my `Request` object `Equatable` so it can now compare all fields appropriately. And I had to remove the `await` from `firestore` calls so that events occur really asynchronously.

Here is an example of working test:

```dart
test('request exists', () async {
      // GIVEN
      final timestamp = DateTime.now();
      final request = Request(
          '49a257e1-c0e3-4cc1-9053-aaf55197f897',
          user.id,
          "${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}",
          user.phone ?? "",
          'center',
          'comment',
          timestamp,
          false,
          false);

      await firestore
          .collection('requests')
          .doc(request.id)
          .set(request.toJson());

      // WHEN
      final stream = repository.observe('id', request.id);

      // THEN
      expect(
          stream,
          emitsInOrder([
            Request(
                '49a257e1-c0e3-4cc1-9053-aaf55197f897',
                user.id,
                "${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}",
                user.phone ?? "",
                'center',
                'comment',
                timestamp,
                false,
                false),
            Request(
                '49a257e1-c0e3-4cc1-9053-aaf55197f897',
                user.id,
                "${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}",
                user.phone ?? "",
                'center',
                'comment',
                timestamp,
                false,
                true),
          ]));

      firestore
          .collection('requests')
          .doc(request.id)
          .set({"completed": true}, SetOptions(merge: true));
    });
```